# Python Apscheduler conditional tasks

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a simple set of functions `foo` and `bar`. I want to run the second job `bar` only after successful completion of the task/function `foo`.

Currently I am doing this with a global variable as such:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

success = 0

def foo():
    global success
    try:
        print 'yes'
    except:
        success = 0
        return
    success = 1
    return

def bar():
    if success:
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'
    return

scheduler = Scheduler()
scheduler.add_cron_job(foo, day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=18, minute=30);
scheduler.add_cron_job(bar, day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=18, minute=45)
scheduler.start()
```

Is there a better way to have conditional tasks with `apscheduler`?

Answer (score 1):

Schedule a new run of bar() in 15 minutes from foo() if it succeeds.

Like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def foo():
    print 'yes'
    scheduler.add_date_job(bar, datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=15))
```

Comment: And please upgrade to APScheduler 3. Thanks :)